# How to display an overlay over the UIWebView without blocking user-interaction with UIWebView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiwebview, overlay

As the question title says, I want to display a light blue overlay on the UIWebView, when the UIWebview is loading and without blocking the user-interaction with UIWebView. Is it possible to get this effect?

Currently I am displaying a partially transparent ligh blue colored UIView over the UIWebView while the UIWebview is loading. But this blocks the user-interaction with UIWebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique I use for overlaying UIPickers should work and that is

1.Create a custom UIButton with the 'overlay' you want as the background.

*I use a custom UIButton simply because it already has transparency but you could use an image view and set its background colour to clearColor.*

2.set userInteraction = NO on the custom button

3.Add the custom UIButton over (in this case the web view) the view

Comment: Thanks. With two small changes in your idea, I got it worked. I set the Alpha of imageView to 0.5 and background color to the matching overlay color.

Comment: Actually this way works really well if you can do it in the xib as everything can be done in the nib without resorting to any code at all.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6740365/821446) answer. It's an answer to other problem, but should be very useful for your case.

Happy coding...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't test your solution as Damo's solution worked with less efforts. But anyway, thanks for your time.